# How to backfill my DAG when it is needed to specify op_kwargs?

Tags: python, airflow

How can I load previous data in my DAG when I am obliged to specify `op_kwargs`? Data updates every 4th, 12th, 18th, and 26th day of month. So I wrote a DAG today, it means that the next run will be on 26th of October. But data which I pull is dating from the 1st of January, 2023. How do I backfill my DB?

```
with DAG(dag_id='load_data_using_api',
         description='Load data to my DB',
         schedule_interval='30 15 4,12,18,26 * *',  # every 4th, 12th, 18th, and 26th day of the month at 15:30 
         start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
         end_date=datetime(2023, 10, 18),
         catchup=True
         ) as dag
```

And my code to execute requires date to be passed:

```
load_categories = PythonOperator(
    task_id='load_categories',
    python_callable=transform_load_categories,
    op_kwargs={'date': '', # WHAT TO WRITE HERE? 
               'token': token['token'],
               'engine': engine}

)
```

What (may be macros) should I write into `op_kwargs` date argument to correctly backfill data?